# Will subquery be executed first here with full scan?

Tags: oracle

I have below query

```
select * 
    from employee employee,
    (select address1.id 
        from address1 add1, address2 add2
        where add1.address2_id = add2.id ) address_data
    where emp.empId = 100
    and emp.address_id = address_data.id 
// index exists  on both columns i.e. address_id and id
```

I was expecting first subquery(`address_data`) will be executed internally and there will be full scan on address1 and address2 table. Then outer
query will be executed.

**Revised understanding after looking at explain plain**

But when I looked at explain plain looks like it is not happening. I found there was not any full scan on address1 and address2 table. Looks like
first outer query executed(which returned only record) and then only relevant records were fetched from address1 and address2 table(just fyi address tabl also returned 1 row).

This strategy looks logical to me as there is no need to do full access of address tables in this case.

**My question -** Is my revised understanding correct ? But I was under impression that sub query will always be executed first. Look like  I was wrong here ?

Comment: Select From Where is processed From Where Select. In the Select portion of the script the system figures out the most efficient way to run the command(this goes for the From portion as well since the process runs on Sets), so it would not always run left-right as is the case in many coding languages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle internally changes your query to optimize it. For this oracle uses one of the techniques listed in the optimization features of Oracle optimizer called query transformation. The techniques are listed in [OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_transform.htm#TGSQL206). The technique that you are observing in your case is called View Merging.

Answer (score 1):

## PLAN

Your understanding of the Plan seems correct.

## Common Misunderstanding

People often forget that SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural language.

You should never assume sub-queries run in a certain order.

Answer (score -1):

Why would the subquery always be executed first?

Example:

```
select
  s.column1,
  (select count(*) from huge_table h where h.column1 = s.column2)
from
  any_table s
where 
  s.id < 0
;
```

Let's say no `s.id` is less than `0`. Because of `s.id < 0` condition, the outer query returns 0 rows. Why would the database scan the `huge_table` without any filtering, just to find out after it in an instant that it was all for nothing, because the outer query returns nothing.